# How to get Google analytics data in azure

Tags: azure, google-analytics, azure-data-factory

I have been asked to get the Google Analytics data (for my company's website) in Azure database. The go to tool for this is to use Azure data factory and any thing and everything that is under the Azure umbrella.

I tried looking for this online, but there's no straight forward to achieve this. Can someone point me to the right resources or a step by step tutorial on how to do this? So far, I have been following [Richard Swinbank's](https://www.richardswinbank.net/adf/access_google_analytics_with_azure_data_factory) tutorial, but I am not entirely sure on how to setup the C# Code within Azure.

Any help is appreciated on this.

Thanks
RV

Comment: you says the Google Analytics data (for my company's website)  is in Azure database(SQL database or others), so the problem is get data from Azure database, am I right?What's  the sink?

Comment: The data is to be extracted from the Google API's and dumped into Azure SQL using Data Factory. The sink is Azure SQL Server databases.

Comment: The tutorial is build an C# Azure Function firstly, then call the Azure function in Data Factory.

Comment: Hi @rvphx, do you have any other concerns or did you figure it out?

Comment: Hi Leon. I decided to go with building out the whole thing in Python. Much easier that way.

Comment: Hello @rvphx, hope things going well. I'm glad you that you choose an easier way. Can I post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is to be extracted from the Google API's and dumped into Azure SQL using Data Factory. The sink is Azure SQL Server databases. You want to setup the C# Code within Azure.

The tutorial you find build an C# Azure Function firstly, then call the Azure function in Data Factory. That may be a little complex.

You finally decided to go with building out the whole thing in Python and it's much easier than achieve that in Data Factory. Anyway, Hope things going well.